# Poisson Arrival Process and Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-process

I'm brushing up on some basic probability and have this question:

If we have a Poisson arrival process with arrivals $A_{1}, A_{2}, \dots$, and we know that there is one and only one arrival in a time period, say $[t_{1}, t_{2}]$. Does this mean that the one arrival is distributed uniformly on $[t_{1},t_{2}]$? How would one go about "proving" (it might be trivial, but not sure) such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

For any bounded set $S\subseteq[0,\infty)$ let $N_S$ denote the number of arrivals in set $S$.

If $T$ denotes an arrival in $(t_1,t_2]$ then for $t\in(t_1,t_2]$ we find:

$$\begin{aligned}P\left(T\leq t\mid N\left(t_{1},t_{2}\right)=1\right) & =\frac{P\left(N_{\left(t_{1},t\right]}=1,N_{\left(t,,t_{2}\right]}=0\right)}{P\left(N_{\left(t_{1},t_{2}\right]}=1\right)}\\
 & =\frac{P\left(N_{\left(t_{1},t\right]}=1\right)P\left(N_{\left(t,,t_{2}\right]}=0\right)}{P\left(N_{\left(t_{1},t_{2}\right]}=1\right)}\\
 & =\frac{e^{-\lambda\left(t-t_{1}\right)}\lambda\left(t-t_{1}\right)e^{-\lambda\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right)}}{e^{-\lambda\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right)}\lambda\left(t_{2}-t_{1}\right)}\\
 & =\frac{t-t_{1}}{t_{2}-t_{1}}
\end{aligned}
$$
So under the condition that there is only one arrival in $(t_1,t_2]$ (i.e. $T$ is *unique* as arrival) $T$ will have uniform distribution on $(t_1,t_2]$.

---

More generally it can be proved for suitable sets $S$ that under the condition that $N_{S}=k$ the set of arrivals has the same distribution as a sample of $k$ iid random variables that have uniform distribution on $S$.

What was handled above is then the special case $k=1$ and $S=(t_1,t_2]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your process $N(t)$. i.e. $N(t)$ is the number of arrivals that have happened up to and including time $t$. And given an interval $(a,b]$, let $N((a,b])$ denote the number of arrivals in the interval $(a,b]$.

The way you would go about proving it is to fix some number $s \in (t_1,t_2]$ and try to calculate
$$
\mathbb{P}\bigl(N(t) < s |\ \text{first arrival is in}\ (t_1,t_2]\bigr).
$$
You are hoping the answer is
$$
\frac{s-t_1}{t_2 - t_1}
$$
The event ''first arrival is in $(t_1,t_2]$'' can be thought of as ''$N(t_1) = 0$ *and* $N(t_2) \geq 1$''.

Comment: Are all arrival in $(t_{1}, t_{2}]$ uniformly distributed or is it just the first one? I'm not sure how to prove this.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it to say $N(t_2) \geq 1$ at the end. I don't know if that helps. Well I'm not sure if you just wanted a hint to get started or more of a proof. You just said how to "go about" proving it. You presumably know some formula for certain probabilities associated with $N$?

Comment: @gtogues Not just the first. When *given that* the arrival of *some* event $A_n$ is the *only* arrival that occurs in interval $(t_1..t_2]$, then the (conditional) probability distribution function for its time of arrival, $T_n$, is evaluated by:$$\mathsf P\big(T_n\leqslant t\mid N_{(t_1..t_2]}=1\cap T_n\in(t_1..t_2]\big)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(N_{(t_1..t]}=1\cap N_{(t..t_2]}=0)}{\mathsf P(N_{(t_1..t_2]}=1)}$$ Where for any time inteval $(u..v]$, the count for arrivals in that interval is Poisson distributed: $N_{(u..v]}\sim\mathcal{Poiss}(\lambda(v-u))$, for an unknown rate $\lambda$.